# Formato condicional propiedad Bold está a null en Epplus.Core 1.5.4

Tags: c#, excel, .net-core, net, epplus

Tengo un Excel que sirve de "plantilla" para descargar datos, esta plantilla, tiene 2 columnas (A y B), la A contiene la información como el nombre, el dni y la dirección (todo se muestra en una fila distinta), como son datos distintos, para identificar el tipo, el usuario pone en la columna B el tipo de esa fila.
De esta forma, se aplica un formato condicional de Excel.

Hasta ahí todo bien, el tipo de fuente, los colores, etc... Pero si el formato condicional tiene un formato con negrita, dicha propiedad no se copia, puesto que siempre viene a null.

Necesitaría que el Excel que se genera, tuviera los formatos condicionales con el formato negrita.

Estoy usando **Net Core 2.2** y **EPPlus.Core 1.5.4**

Estos son los datos:
[image: Estos son los datos]

Estos son los formatos condicionales que intento aplicar:
[image: Estos son los formatos condicionales que intento aplicar]

Muestra del formato con negrita:
[image: Muestra del formato con negrita]

He intentado copiar propiedad por propiedad (Style.Font, Style.Fill..), pero al venir como null, no es posible rescatar nada.

```
    private void ApplyingConditionalFormatting(ExcelWorksheet worksheetBase, ExcelWorksheet worksheetNew)
    {
        var baseConditional = worksheetBase.ConditionalFormatting;
        var newConditional = worksheetNew.ConditionalFormatting;

        foreach (var aux in baseConditional)
        {
            ExcelConditionalFormattingExpression condition = aux as ExcelConditionalFormattingExpression;
            var cfRule = newConditional.AddExpression(new ExcelAddress("A1:A13"));
            cfRule.Formula = "$B1==\"T\"";
            cfRule.Formula = condition.Formula;
            cfRule.Style.Fill = condition.Style.Fill;
            cfRule.Style.Font = condition.Style.Font; // Aquí, viene a null la propiedad Bold
            cfRule.Style.Border = condition.Style.Border;
            cfRule.Style.NumberFormat = condition.Style.NumberFormat;
        }
    }
```

Espero que sea suficiente para ver si alguien ha tenido el mismo problema y lo consiguió solucionar.
Gracias!